# React build gives an error everytime I modify the code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, progressive-web-apps

I am building `PWA` with `React` and every time I change sth in any `js` file I am getting an error. Is it either:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

or

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Both in `main.js` file. It works on `npm start` perfectly tho. It happens o0nly if I do `npm run build` and I modified anything in any `js` file. However, once I refresh the page, the problem disappears until I moidfy sth again and do `run build`. I tried some solutions like adding these two lines just after the `head` in `index.html`:

```
  <script type="text/jsx" src="./index.js"></script>
  <script type="text/babel" src="./index.js"></script>
```

Seems it doesn't help. Also, I added webpack.config.js and put that in it:

```
let path = require('path');
let HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve('dist'),
    filename: 'bundled.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets:['es2015','react']
            }
          }
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "style-loader"
          },
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              modules: true,
              importLoaders: 1,
              localIdentName: "[name]_[local]_[hash:base64]",
              sourceMap: true,
              minimize: true
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html",
      filename: "./index.html"
    })
  ]
};
```

I believe it doesn't even run this script. Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  ...
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "cra-append-sw": "^2.5.0",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "workbox-background-sync": "^3.4.1",
     ...
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "REACT_APP_DEV_API_URL='development' npm start",
    "prod": "REACT_APP_PROD_API_URL='production' npm start",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build && cra-append-sw ./sw.js",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.54",
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.2.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3"
  }
}
```

And this is my project structure.

[image]

Comment: I wonder why would you modify a js file after a build and how you see that in the browser. Are you using the configuration done by `create-react-app`? If so, did you `eject` you app ? 
`start` is probably running webpack dev server and serving an in memory copy of your compiled code, while after `build` the files are under the `build` directory. If you provide some more details on your setup it might help clarifying the issue

Comment: I didn't mean that I modify the code during the app runs but if sth has changed in the code since last build and I create a new build then I get an error. Is it clear now?

Comment: The setup created with `create-react-app` requires you to run `eject` to be able to modify the webpack config files. Those are placed under the `config` folder. There are different files for dev and prod. This at least should bring you closer to have full control over the configuration